# Setting a default language for google translate

Tags: php, wordpress, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using google translate for my Core PHP project.The issue I am facing is when I set english as a default language i.e. if any user opens the website in any other country the default language pf page transaltion would be English.I have added this code which works fine If any user open site in Dubai

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  setCookie('googtrans', '/en/en',1);
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    includedLanguages: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
 }
 function setCookie(key, value, expiry) {
  var expires = new Date();
  expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
 }
```

The issue is it sets the default language to English but it changes the google traslation dropdown values to arabic.Here is the screenshot.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8zeE.png)

I am pretty much stuck in this.Any help would be appreciated.

I did some R and D on how google translation works and added some code also but it did not work upto my expectations.

Comment: Nothing in the code you have shown indicates "Arabic", so my guess would be that Google probably uses the browser language to determine what language to display the translate widget in. (And I am guessing your users in Dubai probably do have that set to Arabic?)

Comment: Can we disable choosing browser language ?
The problem is I have set cookie for default language to be english if user open website from Dubai which is working fine But the dropdown language is converted to arabic which is not correct